# PHP multi dimension array merge with nested items

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to produce a single array from the below code. At the moment it is producing an multiple array wit mostly the same data. The only part that has multiple option is the 'groups'item in the array. Essentially i would like 1 array with the multiples being in a nested array.

```
$result = $c['db']->select(
    "SELECT users.*, user_details.*, user_roles.role, user_groups.*, groups.* 
    FROM users, user_details, user_roles, user_groups, groups 
    WHERE users.user_id = 2
    AND user_details.user_id = users.user_id
    AND user_roles.role_id = users.user_role
    AND user_groups.user_id = users.user_id
    AND user_groups.group_id = groups.group_id
     "
);

if (! $result) {
    return null;
}

return (object) array(
    'id' => (int) $result['user_id'],
    'email' => $result['email'],
    'username' => $result['username'],
    'first_name' => $result['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $result['last_name'],
    'confirmed' => $result['confirmed'] == 'Y',
    'role' => $result['role'],        
    'role_id' => (int) $result['user_role'],
    'groups' => array (
            'group_name' => $result['group'],                 
        ),
    'phone' => $result['phone'],
    'address' => $result['address'],
    'is_banned' => $result['banned'] == 'Y',
    'is_admin' => strtolower($result['role']) === 'admin',
    'last_login' => $result['last_login']
);
};
```

This currently produces the following array:

```
(
[0] =>; Array
    (
        [user_id] =>; 2
        [email] =>; this@that.com
        [username] =>; sam
        [password] =>; $2a$13$axDJv7uljBmryyYoH4w0I.9sDuqjegPOh0WE4gX5UmMh4MbqfMLc.
        [confirmation_key] =>; 
        [confirmed] =>; Y
        [password_reset_key] =>; 
        [password_reset_confirmed] =>; N
        [password_reset_timestamp] =>; 
        [register_date] =>; 2017-12-12
        [user_role] =>; 2
        [last_login] =>; 2017-12-18 10:53:00
        [banned] =>; N
        [id_user_details] =>; 2
        [first_name] =>; 
        [last_name] =>; 
        [phone] =>; 
        [address] =>; 
        [role] =>; editor            
        [group] =>; owners
    )

[1] =>; Array
    (
        [user_id] =>; 2
        [email] =>; this@that.com
        [username] =>; sam
        [password] =>; $2a$13$axDJv7uljBmryyYoH4w0I.9sDuqjegPOh0WE4gX5UmMh4MbqfMLc.
        [confirmation_key] =>; 
        [confirmed] =>; Y
        [password_reset_key] =>; 
        [password_reset_confirmed] =>; N
        [password_reset_timestamp] =>; 
        [register_date] =>; 2017-12-12
        [user_role] =>; 2
        [last_login] =>; 2017-12-18 10:53:00
        [banned] =>; N
        [id_user_details] =>; 2
        [first_name] =>; 
        [last_name] =>; 
        [phone] =>; 
        [address] =>; 
        [role] =>; editor
        [group_id] =>; 2
        [group] =>; mentors
    )

)
```

The desired output is for there to be multiple 'group' items nested.
I somehow need to loop over

```
'groups' => array (
            'group_name' => $result['group'],                 
        ),
```

Comment: Don't understand :( Do you want array with only group names?

Comment: I need to group and nest [group] =>. As there will be multiple groups. At the moment it produces 2. [group] =>; mentors and [group] =>; owners. I need them under the same parent all under a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would would build up an array of group names before returning the result

```
if (! $result) {
     return null;
}

$group_names = array();

foreach($result as $result_row) {
     $group_names[] = $result_row['group']
}

return (object) array(
    'id' => (int) $result[0]['user_id'],
    'email' => $result[0]['email'],
    'username' => $result[0]['username'],
    'first_name' => $result[0]['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $result[0]['last_name'],
    'confirmed' => $result[0]['confirmed'] == 'Y',
    'role' => $result[0]['role'],        
    'role_id' => (int) $result[0]['user_role'],
    'groups' => array (
            'group_name' => $group_names,                 
    ),
    'phone' => $result[0]['phone'],
    'address' => $result[0]['address'],
    'is_banned' => $result[0]['banned'] == 'Y',
    'is_admin' => strtolower($result[0]['role']) === 'admin',
    'last_login' => $result[0]['last_login']
);
```

That code isn't very elegant but I didn't want to change too much from what you already had. Some object relational mapping tools will do this kind of conversion for you but they usually also want you to define the relationships between your tables in advance. It is probably a lot of work to retrofit one of these technologies into your code base but you may want to consider learning one of the following for your next project.

- http://www.doctrine-project.org/
- http://lessql.net/
- http://phpdatamapper.com/